# How closely did When Worlds Collide authors pursue the physics of the catastrophic damage and planet trajectories?

Tags: physics, plot-device, authors, when-worlds-collide

After writing [this comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28327/if-a-giant-object-would-approach-the-earth-would-earth-start-to-turn-faster-or#comment50228_28327) I thought of the 1933 novel [When Worlds Collide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Worlds_Collide) co-written by Philip Wylie and Edwin Balmer.

> South African astronomer Sven Bronson discovers that a pair of rogue planets, Bronson Alpha and Bronson Beta, will soon enter the solar system. **In eight months, they will pass close enough to cause catastrophic damage to the Earth**. Sixteen months later, **after swinging around the Sun, Bronson Alpha will return to pulverize the Earth and leave. It is hoped that Bronson Beta will remain and assume a stable orbit.**

Wikipedia describes the catastrophic damage from the first pass in the novel as

> Tidal waves sweep inland at a height of 750 feet (230 m), volcanic eruptions and earthquakes add to the deadly toll, and the weather runs wild for more than two days. As a token of things to come, Bronson Alpha grazes and destroys the Moon.

Is it known if the authors drew upon the known science of the day to hypothesize what the effects of a planetary near approach would be like? I know it's nearly 100 years ago, but I'm curious how they came up with the science behind the induced tidal waves, and volcanos and earthquakes. The Moon grazing means the approach of at least one of the planets to Earth was less than 400,000 km, so if they'd assumed a mass for the planets, they could estimate quantitatively the forces on the Earth.

The fact that Bronson Alpha and Beta split up and have different, well described orbits suggests they'd certainly put some thought into the orbital mechanics, but I don't know if the orbits are realistic, nor if it was Earth's gravity or the interaction with the Moon that split Alpha and Beta. Is it known to what level of detail they had pursued all of the physics involved in the catastrophic damage and planet trajectories?

Comment: @user14111 aha, a datapoint! If you can find a way to post a quote and cite the essay, either in a partial answer or comment, I would really appreciate it! I'd love to read anything about it possible. Thanks!

Comment: @user14111 *great stuff, thank you!* If nothing more definitive turns up in the next 2 days I would like to be able to accept this as an answer, as long as a source for the Moskowitz quotes can be cited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Sam Moskowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Moskowitz), prominent old-time fan and historian of science fiction, wrote an essay on [Philip Wylie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Wylie) in his [*Studies in Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?25799) series. Titled ["Philip Wylie: The Saccharine Cynic"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?729517), it was originally published in [*Fantastic Science Fiction Stories*, September 1960](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?228141+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v09n09_1960-09#page/n59/mode/2up); it was reprinted (without the subtitle) in [*Science Fantasy*, October 1961](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60277), also available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Science_Fantasy_v17n49_1961-10_dtsg0318#page/n75/mode/2up).

According to Moskowitz, Wylie considered himself a stickler for scientific accuracy (his collaborator [Edwin Balmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Balmer) not so much), and consulted some unnamed friends at Caltech about the physics of *When Worlds Collide*.

> A bug on astronomy, Balmer had roughed out a sequence of events for a novel where two planets enter our solar system from outer space. One will strike
> the earth with resultant mutual destruction. The only chance man has for survival is to build space ships and transfer a few thousand men and women to the second invading world — which will take up an orbit around the sun — before it moves out of range. He presented this idea to Wylie and found a kindred spirit. Like a child with a new toy, **Philip Wylie assembled his physicist friends at Cal Tech and mathematically mapped out the scientific elements by which this feat of [spacial] leap frog could be accomplished.** The time lost in the advancement of atomics was unquestionably science fiction's gain.
>
> The collaboration, written as *These Shall Not Die*, was retitled *When Worlds Collide* by Donald Kennicott and opened in the September, 1932 issue of BLUE BOOK.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> There seemed no question that a third book in the series, solving the riddle of the new planet's missing inhabitants was the next logical step, and indeed a plot was outlined by Balmer but vetoed by Wylie. Every word of *When Worlds Collide* had been
> written by Wylie and it had been published as written. Similarly, **Wylie wrote all of the text of the sequel, but before press time Balmer made some alterations that affected scientific plausibility. Wylie, a purist at science fiction nurtured in the tradition of Jules Verne, H. G. Wells and Hugo Gernsback, was disturbed by these changes. Balmer's plot outline of the third book would have been difficult to validate on the basis of known facts. Wylie contended that the success of the first two volumes was predicated, to a large extent, upon the high degree of respect shown for scientific accuracy.** Therefore, though he continued to collaborate with Balmer on adventure and detective novels, he refused to give literary substance to the projected third in the *When Worlds Collide* series.

Comment: I don't care how many "physicists" worked on the math; the trajectory fails simple tests of common sense.  1I/2017 U1 ('Oumuamua) had a velocity at 1AU of c.50km/s and spent a total of just _2 months_ at a distance of less than 1 AU from the sun.  The Bronson bodies already had a velocity at _Saturn's_ orbital distance of at least 80km/s (Ch.3, from Neptune to Saturn in about 11 mo) and so could not have taken *more* than 2 months between crossings of Earth's orbit.

Comment: @DavidW this is really intriguing! I'm going to have to locate a copy in Taipei and read it now.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, they both get the collision itself completely wrong. Let me elaborate.

In the novel, Wylie and Balmer describe the collision of Earth and Bronson Alpha as "decillions of tons of mass colliding in cosmic catastrophe".  A little later, they describe shattered fragments of the Earth assuming stable orbits of their own around the Sun.  First of all, real planets simply do not behave in this fashion when they come within several million miles of each other, let alone on a collision course.  And if it's the latter, they certainly do *not* still retain their original solid, pre-collision, shape.

How do I know this?  Two simple words:  **tidal forces!** Any celestial body the size of the Earth, if acted upon by the enormous gravity of another celestial body the size of Bronson Alpha, would immediately start to distend itself grotesquely in the direction of the approaching other body until it assumed an egg-shape with the pointy end in the direction of the other body.  And vice versa ala Alpha.  It, too, would immediately distend itself towards Earth and assume an egg-shape of its own.

So what you would have would be two giant egg-shaped planetary bodies being slowly ripped apart by unbelievably powerful tidal forces long before they ever got within even one moon orbit's distance from each other, let alone physically colliding like two intact cosmic billiard balls in space, like in the novel.  Celestial physics simply will not permit this.

Which further means that no one will ever be able to save themselves from such an imminent catastrophe in time to be decisive.  The entire world would have been ripped to pieces without actually colliding with the other planet at all.  Worse, the Earth would have already completely melted, perhaps even been vaporized, by said tidal forces, before even being ripped apart, because of latent heat.  And obviously, the other body would not be immune to these effects either.

In the end, our precious Earth (and Alpha) would be reduced by the combined effect of the two planets' tidal forces upon each other to a vast cloud of floating rock vapor in space which could conceivably re-coalesce into a brand new planet twice the size of the original Earth, given enough time. But, of course, no one would be around anymore to take advantage of this!

Just thought I'd point out this little, not-so-nit-picky, detail to anyone reading this site because it's something that's always bothered me about the novel.  The end of the world, if it ever does happen, won't be anywhere near as neat and orderly as Wylie and Balmer imagined.  It'll actually be way, *way* worse! And unlike the famous REM song, we will most definitely *not* be feeling fine!

Other than that, I actually really loved the book and consider it, sans collision, to be perhaps the single greatest sci-fi book ever written anywhere by anyone.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You have some good points, though your post could use more paragraphs and fewer exclamation marks. :)  Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the kind of answer the person posting the question wants to hear, so it may not be well-received.  You could make this a better answer by providing some rough approximations, for example of how much tidal heating would occur just to demonstrate your argument is based in real-world physics.

Comment: I'm " the person posting the question" and this would be more "the kind of answer" I'd "wants to hear" if it were a little more quantitative. In [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32061/7982) I calculated that the tidal forces on Earth at the moment of contact with Jupiter would be 0.4 g on the side facing Jupiter, which is not enough to "tear the Earth apart" or even lift small objects off of the surface. That's because Earth's center of mass would be *accelerating towards Jupiter* at roughly 2 g already.

Comment: If you reached out and tried to hold the Earth's center of mass in place, then Jupiter's gravity would pull the rest of the Earth apart. But as a free body in space, *the gradient* of Jupiter's gravity alone would not do that. I don't know Bronson Alpha's radius and mass is nor the distance of closest approach, and the fact that those numbers don't appear in your answer means it's unfounded speculation. It seems to me that it's more like "I always wanted to *say this* so here it goes" than it is an answer to the question as asked. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: But if you'd like to add those three numbers to your answer then we could work it out, but it would have to be in a context remaining close to the goal of providing an answer to the question as asked.

Comment: Thank you all for your prescient comments regarding my admittedly rather convoluted explanation concerning the likely physical effects of a cosmic collision between Earth and another much larger planet.  Good points, all.  I'm sorry if my answer wasn't more mathematically quantitative.  My higher math skills are somewhat lacking in equational coherence, particularly as they pertain to celestial mechanics.  But I promise you all I'm going to bone up on that real soon!  Consider today's interesting, if mathematically unfounded, explanation of mine a test case.  I will get better at this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist giving another answer here.  It directly relates to the novel.  The authors mention Alpha coming to within the same distance from the Earth as the Moon but 90 degrees from the plane of the ecliptic.  Up from the south, so to speak. They also say that Alpha is about the size of Uranus, give or take a few thousand miles.  That means that Alpha is roughly 32,000 miles in diameter which, in visual terms, means it's four Earth diameters wide.  In volume, Alpha would hold up to 63 Earths with room to spare.  That's a whole lot of planet to pick a cosmic fight with.  In terms..

Comment: ...of Alpha's effects on the Earth during its first approach,  I believe that the authors vastly underestimate the catastrophic scale of Alpha's gravity upon the Earth.  They mention tides of 750 high girdling the globe as Alpha passes by at its closest approach.   This all occurring, of course, at the same time it's taking out the Moon, which, now that I think of it, would have almost certainly added to Alpha's overall mass, thus increasing its gravity even more, making it even more dangerous to us six months later on the other side of the Sun when it would swing back down upon the Earth and

Comment: take it out from above.  The author's say that Alpha's gravity split the Earth wide open like a burst grape, that the world practically groaned in agony at the capricious effects of the strangers from space.  The center of Africa was literally split in two as if by a giant meat cleaver, unleashing the hell that dwelt at the center of the Earth, meaning an entire ocean of magma.  Every volcano in the Ring of Fire erupted simultaneously.  The Rockies danced and leaped like galloping horses. Also the Andes.  It was as if Alpha had Earth in a cosmic choke-hold.

Comment: As bad as all this was, in reality, it would have been a hundred times worse, possibly bad enough to completely destroy Earth's crust.  And as for those monstrous tides, 750  feet high would have been a minor splash compared to their true heights which would have been measured in MILES!! Perhaps even beyond the top of the atmosphere!  The authors are correct, however, in assuming that a planet the size of Alpha coming that close to Earth would, at a bare minimum, completely rearrange the map of the world beyond all recognition.  They mention the Mississippi Valley being transformed...

Comment: into a vast inland sea reaching as far north as Chicago.  And the Eastern Seaboard is completely flooded all the way to the Appalachians.  In fact, only a few areas of the world remain dry land, including, and especially, the upper peninsula of Michigan, which is the place the scientists chose to build their atomic-powered rocketship to blast them all to Bronson Beta just before the world ends.

Comment: Sorry this got so long but I really know this book by heart and I'm trying to either rebut or confirm the author's sometimes highly accurate speculations about such an unprecedented event as the collision of worlds.  So please allow me some leeway if you all would. Thanks.  Let me now extend my argument to the all-important realm of HEAT!!!!  The amount of heat that would be generated by even an approach of another planetary body to the Earth is literally astronomical.  As I said before, Alpha's gravity would have, in all likelihood, completely destroyed the Earth's crust by melting it.

Comment: As for the oceans, in addition to being lifted bodily from their beds by Alpha in the mother of all tsunamis, they would then have been instantly converted into steam almost immediately after due to the enormous heat generated by the friction caused from having all those quintillions of tons of water suddenly hurled out of the oceanic basins and slammed down upon the land with enough force to generate a magnitude 10000 on the Richter scale!!  Imagine that for a second.  The entire contents of all the worlds oceans suspended in the air in one vast, globe-girdling steam cloud.

Comment: The contents of which would immediately start to precipitate out in the greatest rainstorm in history.  That is, if a significant part of the atmosphere itself hadn't already been sucked off into space by Alpha's gravity.  Think about that, too.  The authors don't go into any of this, not really.  They do, however, give a vivid description of the psychological effects of witnessing phenomena that belonged not on Earth but in the Cosmos.  It's devastatingly accurate.  Though they themselves did not know it at the time, we now have real science to back up their speculations on the effects of

Comment: planetary collisions.  It's the science of conservation of angular momentum and the laws of thermodynamics as they relate to the formation of the Moon.  The current consensus theory about the Moon's formation is that it was created from a giant impact that occurred between the primitive Earth of 4.5 billion years ago and a Mars-sized object scientists have named Orpheus or Theia, depending on who you ask.  According to their theory, this rogue planet once occupied the same orbit as Earth, which apparently was quiet commonplace back then in the inner solar system.

Comment: Anyway, the law of averages being what it is, at some point, the inevitable occurred:  The two planets collided in a massive impact that briefly destroyed both worlds from the heat of the impact.  But not so much that Orpheus was completely absorbed by the Earth. No, what actually happened was a one in a google-plex chance event that created the Moon and guaranteed that our world would eventually have life on it someday.  Orpheus struck the Earth at an oblique angle, wrenching it 23 1/2 degrees from the vertical, thus giving it seasons for the first time and speeding up its rotation as well.

Comment: So fast, in fact, that the day after the impact would have only lasted nine hours!  Nine hours long!  The Earth was whirling so fast it was generating sustained winds of thousands of miles an hour, faster than all the hurricanes and tornadoes combined.  But out of the massive amount of debris spalled off by the collision, just enough of it was hurled beyond Earth's Roche Limit, which meant that that debris would remain in orbit long enough to coalesce into the Moon in, by some estimates, only a year!  The core of Orpheus meanwhile sank down to the center of the Earth to merge with its own core

Comment: thus forming a new supercore,capable now, because of the sudden influx of heavy metals like iron and nickel, of generating a massive magnetic field, which is what protects us to this day from deadly solar flares and other cosmic radiation. Meanwhile, back up top, 70% of the original primordial crust of the Earth had been blasted into space to form the Moon, thus allowing for tectonic plates to move around through the spaces left behind by the now missing crust. Amazing, isn't it.  Our planet has the most efficient method of internal heat transfer of any planet in the solar system.

Comment: All because of the impact that triggered it in the first place!  Venus does not have plate tectonics because it still has all of its original crust in place on the planet. No collision blasted it away.  Thus, there is no room for any of it to move around for heat to transfer outward from the center of the planet.  Venus compensates for this by periodically undergoing massive planetwide vulcanism once every few hundred million years or so to let the heat out all at once because it's been bottled up by all that crust still in its way.  Not Earth.  We've never had that problem.

Comment: Instead, we've had one very large and very lucky Moon to stabilize and slow down our original high rate of rotation to the current 24 hour a day cycle and to minimize the planetary wobble as it undergoes the 25,000 year cycle of the precession of the equinoxes due to the 23 and a half degree tilt imparted on it by Orpheus over 4 billion years ago.  This theory perfectly explains the observable facts about the Earth-Moon system by interpreting it entirely in terms of the conservation of angular momentum between the two bodies. Originally, the Moon was only about 10,000 miles from the Earth,

Comment: close enough to generate tides as high as those described in When Worlds Collide and actually much higher. But gradually, over millions of years, the friction generated by the violent scouring of the oceans from the Moon's enormous gravity forced the Earth's rotation to slow down, which in turn, caused the Moon to begin to go further and further away from it's original close-in orbit.  It now orbits at a quite safe distant of 240,000 miles and the tides here on Earth have calmed down considerably.  In so many ways, we need the Moon to survive on Earth.  It keeps the Earth profoundly stable.

Comment: compared to the other planets of the inner solar system like Mars, for instance, whose poles periodically tip all the way over to the equator and back again, creating wild climatological oscillations.  Life would have had a near impossible time to take hold on such a planet as Mars.  It has no large moon to stabilize it. Neither do Venus or Mercury.  Only us.  We are truly unique in this way.  The Rare Earth Hypothesis it's called by some scientists.  Bottom line, no Moon, no US! In the cosmic sweepstakes, did we ever luck out big time!  And all because on one day in our remote past, the Earth

Comment: rolled a snake eyes when it met up with Orpheus.  But that collision dealt it four aces.  And it's never looked back.  So, yes worlds CAN collide!  We're the living proof!  Which makes Philip Wylie and Edwin Balmer more right than they ever knew.  I hope I've managed to entertain and inform all you fine gentlemen tonight with this rather lengthy and convoluted explanation of the physics of planetary collisions but I felt I owed it to you all given your own obvious backgrounds in this field.  I welcome your input on what I have written.  Thanks for reading.  Good night all.

Comment: With your extension of this answer in the form of seventeen comments in a row, the system raised an automatic moderator flag for so many comments :-) I haven't read everything in detail - would these comments of yours also fit within your answer itself? You can always [edit] your own posts if you want to add something. Comments on Stack Exchange are normally treated as ephemeral and unreliable, so if you have extra information that does answer the question (not just tangential commentary), it's good to put it in an answer if possible.